# How to let 2 socket join the same room to chat (socket.io)

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I have a problem but researched many days but still do not resolve it.
I do project chat user to user socket.io and nodejs.
I am user A, when I click a user B on list user on app, It will let user A and B join the same room (`set roomname is (IdOfUserA)_(IdOfUserB)` ).
How can i do the same on server-side, please help me or show me the post with similar problem.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo-code I would do something like this :

On the client side

```
socket.emit('chat-with-user-b', {userb : IdOfUserB}); 
socket.on('chat-with-me', function(roomID){
   // open tchat etc..
});
```

On the server side :

```
io.on("connection", function(socket){
   socket.on('chat-with-user-b', function(IdOfUserB){
      var roomID = IdOfUserB + '_' + socket.id; // create a unique room id
      socket.join(roomID); // make user A join room
      io.sockets[IdOfUserB].join(roomID); // make user B join  room
      io.sockets.in(roomID).emit('chat-with-me', roomID);  // send join event to both.
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand io.sockets[withUser].join(roomID), withUser is IdOfUserB on client which can specify the sockets of User B?

Comment: It was indeed a little confusing, I updated the example. Hope it helps

Comment: So IdOfUserB is socket.id of User B, right? How can take socket.id of User B on client to do socket.emit('chat-with-user-b', {userb : IdOfUserB}).

Comment: On connection you could send the list of connected sockets in a very simplistic way it could be done like this: 
`io.on("connection", function(socket){
   socket.emit('list-of-clients', io.sockets.connected);
..
}`

On the client :
socket.on('list-of-client', function(list){
   list.each(....) // do something like displaying
}`